# Running executable that takes arguments using Python

Tags: python, exe

I am writing a small python script where I open an existing executable (.exe) and I send a string as an argument.

I am using the subprocess.call method and I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 537, in call
   with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 767, in __init__
   raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
TypeError: bufsize must be an integer
```

My code

```
import os
import subprocess

x = subprocess.call("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Program\\Program.exe", y)
```

where y is a string I am passing.

I am trying to upgrade an old VB code. The original code calls the executable and passes an argument as shown below. I am trying to replicate this in Python.

```
Private comm As ExecCmd
Dim cmd As String
Dim app As String
Dim e As New ExecCmd

exec_1= "...\Desktop\Program.exe"
x = "Text" & Variable & " Hello" & Variable2

comm.StartApp exec_1, x   'starts the .exe file with an argument
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command and arguments should be in a list

```
x = subprocess.call(["C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Program\\Program.exe", y])
```

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I placed all the arguments in a list and it worked.

Comment: Do you happen to know how can I read the output of the executable? I tried this and I get an error: `x = subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Program\\Program.exe", y], stdout=PIPE)` where PIPE is not defined.

Comment: Read the docs.  `PIPE` is an attribute of the subprocess module, use `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`   But if you need pipes you should be using the `popen` class or `subprocess.check_output`

Comment: Thanks, it works. This what I did: `subprocess.check_output(["C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Program\\Program.exe", y])`. The output is then converted to a string by using the .decode()

Answer (score 4):

Put the program and any arguments you want into an array first.

```
import os
import subprocess

x = subprocess.call(["C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Program\\Program.exe", y])
```